# Problem with dockerize aspnet core application tutorial

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I'm following this docker tutorial for aspnet core. I built 1 aspnet core template project with swagger and it works fine. I have a problem with the docker file they instruct. Can someone help me.Tks.

Docs:https://docs.docker.com/samples/dotnetcore/

My repository : https://github.com/ThanhDeveloper/WebApplicationAspNetCoreTemplate/tree/DockerIntegration

Error when run command `docker build -t abc .`

I tried to change engine/examples with `../AspNetCoreTemplate ./` or `./AspNetCoreTemplate ./` but it didn't fix the error

```
nguyenthanh@MacBook-Pro-cua-Nguyen AspNetCoreTemplate % docker build -t abc .
[+] Building 0.4s (12/14)                                                                                                                        
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 477B                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0                                                                        0.3s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0                                                                           0.3s
 => [build-env 1/6] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0@sha256:3ca1a372ff025d1f84bb2bef7dbb7c284ea3b49e00bcd0047336b9bca9f8dfb7           0.0s
 => [stage-1 1/3] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0@sha256:ca2e100d2c30490f7cb34ab737bc33e9bd7e533446f6c3356c082caccae7be1a          0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 47B                                                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [build-env 2/6] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1 2/3] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CANCELED [build-env 3/6] COPY *.csproj ./                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [build-env 4/6] RUN dotnet restore                                                                                               0.0s
 => ERROR [build-env 5/6] COPY ../engine/examples ./                                                                                        0.0s
------
 > [build-env 5/6] COPY ../engine/examples ./:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/engine/examples" not found: not found
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot copy from outside the build context. So `COPY ../engine/examples ./` is failing because docker cannot traverse the `../` to go up a level.

All files you want to copy must be accessible from the within the docker context (`.` in this case)

Comment: Tks for your reply. I tried with ```COPY ./ ./``` and it is working for me